# SOAP fault with default WSDL from Magento Website

Tags: magento-1.7, soap

I am using the WSDL (advertised in the Magento Website to be used with Java) in my Android Application.

For simulating the request/response i am using SOAP UI. I deployed Magento on a WAMP server on my local windows machine.

Now when i run any of the SOAP API's I am getting a SOAP fault. Upon analysis found that the below line present in all the internal WSDL files in magento is the cause of this problem -

```
<import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
```

When I comment this line, everything seems to work fine.
But I don't think that this is the correct solution ...

Anyone who faced this issue , please help out !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the SoapUI application not the wsdl itself. I can confirm that the wsdl file is valid.
I don't know if this is the issue for you,  but I had an encoding problem related to SoapUI and it was solved by adding this:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

inside `oapUI-4.6.4\bin\SoapUI-4.6.4.vmoptions`. The folder and file name may depend on the SoapUI version.

Comment: I will slightly modify my question here. I invoked this SOAP Api's from java code (Using KSoap). I face the same issue.So i guess the issue might not be specific to SOAP UI

Comment: @Dibzmania. You might be right. I was just shooting in the dark. One thing is clear. I was able to use the wsdl with php and java. Sorry I cannot do more.